# Fixed DIV not covered by following DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a "fixed" DIV on the very top of my page:

```
<div id="banner-wrapper">
    <div id="banner"></div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#banner-wrapper {
width:300px;
height:500px;
}
#banner {
width:300px;
height:500px;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background:orange;
}
```

This "fixed" DIV is followed by a "content-wrapper" DIV:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content-left">
     content left
    </div>
    <div id="content-right">
     content right or sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#content-wrapper {
width:300px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
top:500px;
bottom:0;
}
#content-left {
width:150px;
float:left;
}
#content-right {
width:150px;
float:right;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the "content-wrapper" DIV does not fully cover the "fixed" DIV. The top of the "content-wrapper" covers the "fixed" DIV and the bottom of "content-wrapper" becomes transparent, showing the "fixed" DIV beneath.

I was able to solve the problem by giving the "body" a height in CSS. However, I do not want to give the "body" a height as I do not know the true hight of the content and would like it to remain flexible. I've also have tried inserting

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

before the closing  tags but it does not force the "content-wrapper" down.

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/FormatMyBook/r8794fss/2/) of the issue on JSFiddle.

As you can see, the "red" box does not reach the "blue" box even though it is set to absolute, bottom 0. From what I can tell it reaches the bottom if it does not contain any DIVs inside of it. But once I add the "content-x" DIVs, it no longer reaches the bottom of the page.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why would anything 'cover' a fixed div?

Comment: I have a banner on the very top of the page that is fixed. The content that follows must scroll on top of the fixed div so that the fixed div does not show once you scroll over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could relatively position the element `#content-wrapper` rather than absolutely positioning it. Then you can omit the `top`/`bottom` positioning and it will behave as expected.

The reason it wasn't working in the first place was because you were giving the absolutely positioned element a height of `100%`. Therefore it will have the same height is the window, which is not what you wanted.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u28zd0mL/)

Change the following:

```
#content-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

to:

```
#content-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. That did the trick. One little issue is that now there is a small gap at the bottom of the page. It looks like 10px of margin that appears under the footer. Not sure why it's there. here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/FormatMyBook/r8794fss/4/

Comment: @SomeDude That's from the default 8px `margin` on the `body` element. Remove it with `body { margin: 0; }`.. updated example - https://jsfiddle.net/98fo3fqy/

Comment: I do have body set to zero padding and margin. I'll double check things. It seems your version of JSfiddle does not have that gap but my version does. I shall compare and see where I've gone wrong.

Thank you Josh. You rock!